# C# - Fechar Formulário sem Parar Aplicação

Tags: c#, winforms, formulário

Olá, estou utilizando C#, para criar um sistema de Login. E gostaria de saber alguma formula para fechar essa janela de login sem que pare a aplicação.
Utilizei o this.Hide(); para esconder o formulário, mas ao fechar o programa ele continua rodando só que oculto. Alguém pode me ajudar?
Lembrando que ao digitar o usuário e a senha correto chamará um outro formulário.

É esse o codigo que estou usando:

```
if (usuarioTextBox.Text == "Administração" && senhaTextBox.Text == "@dmin321")
            {
               MessageBox.Show("Acesso Permitido");
               this.Hide();
               Form2 novoFormulario = new Form2();
               novoFormulario.Show();
            }
```

Comment: Ao fechar a aplicação, o formulário que você tinha escondido com `this.Hide()`, continua rodando? Pode me mostrar isso?

Comment: @Vinicius acho que quando ele diz _ao fechar o programa ele continua rodando_ na verdade ele quer dizer _ao fechar o segundo form, o primeiro form continua rodando_ . Acho que é isso :-)

Comment: É isso mesmo Igor Venturelli

Comment: Legal @Tec.Alves . Você viu a minha resposta? Acredito ser o que você precisa.

Comment: eu faria como o amigo leo longhi, o form principal da aplicacao é o form1, e antes de executa-lo, chamo o formlogin e valido o usuario, se for valido, apenas continuo com a aplicacao, se nao, fecho.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode mudar de `.Show()` para `.ShowDialog()` e fechar seu form quando o segundo form estiver `disposed`:

```
if (usuarioTextBox.Text == "Administração" && senhaTextBox.Text == "@dmin321")
{
    MessageBox.Show("Acesso Permitido");
    Hide();
    Form2 novoFormulario = new Form2();
    novoFormulario.ShowDialog();
    if(novoFormulario.IsDisposed)
        Close();
}
```

Além disso, no segundo form, é necessário chamar o método `Dispose();` no evento `FormClosing`:

```
private void Form2_FormClosing(Object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e) 
{
    Dispose();
}
```

---

Ao chamar o método `Dispose();` você garante que todos os recursos utilizados pelo segundo form foram fechados/encerrados.

Answer (score 2):

Quando quiser encerrar por completo o uso da sua aplicação use o **Application Exit**, você pode coloca-lo no evento **FormClosed** do(s) formulário(s):

```
private void Form1_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Exit();
    }
```

Dessa forma toda aplicação será encerrada.

Answer (score 2):

Sugestão: por que ao invés de chamar primeiro o form de login, não começa pelo segundo, assim ele pode chamar o login e se obter permissão de login continuar!
pode mudar o primeiro form a ser chamado no *Program.cs*

```
static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Form2 ());
    }
```

Trocando Form1 por Form2

e no load do form 2 pode chamar pelo Form1(Login)

```
Visible = false;
Form1 Login= new Form1();
          Login.ShowDialog();
```

encerrando com alguma condição de verdadeiro ou falso para tornar ou não o form visible (caso login seja permitido)